# rotated math symbol in caption

Tags: captions

I made a new math symbol by rotating an existing math symbol. Now I would like to use it in the caption of a table. However, it does not compile. Here a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\nw}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$w$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        some & table
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{$\nw$}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Did I mess something up? If not, what would be a good workaround?

Comment: your example did not load `graphicx` to define `\rotatebox` assuming that was not the error in your real document, the example now runs without error in current latex, but on older releases you will need `\protect\nw` . Please always give the _exact_ error message from the  log file, not "won't compile" which is hard to debug.

Comment: Which vintage of which TeX distribution do you employ? The reason I ask is that your sample code does *not* appear to generate any issues under TeXLive2021.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot. That indeed answers my question. Apparently I did not Google well enough.
I also apologize for not giving the error log and messing up the minimal example. I am new to this. Thanks a bunch for helping out!

Comment: And also good to know that your version matters a lot

Comment: @Mico a release before I did this:  `% \changes{v1.2a}{2019/11/30}{Add \cs{protected} gh/208}`